# How to get facebook friends list using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have tried

```
FB.api('/me/taggable_friends?limit=500', function(response) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
}
```

Which gives me only administrators fb friends list

**For other fb users - below error message**

To use **taggable_friends** on behalf of people who are not admins, developers and testers of your app, your use of this endpoint **must be reviewed and approved by Facebook**. To submit this feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

As I have already submitted my app for review and below is a screenshot that showing that I have an access of Friend List

[image]

If I use [Facebook Developer Link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/friend-list) for friend list then I don't know how to get and set **"/{friend-list-id}"**

```
/* make the API call */
FB.api(
    "/{friend-list-id}",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

Please let me know if is there any working example for this or this is possible or not.

Comment: `console.log(response);`  what is the content of response?

Comment: @FastSnail, its working for taggable_friends but only for admin login of the app

Comment: What I have to pass in place of `{friend-list-id}` if I use developer facebook javascript sdk ?

Comment: i think you better use first one taggable friends .instead of me try to pass userid `{user-id}/taggable_friends`.you can get the userid from your app

Comment: App id is itself an userId Or I have to use user Token @FastSnail ?

Comment: no.userid is who use your app.for example if  i'm using it then user id is my id

Comment: I have passed userId too, but still it giving me an error of `To use taggable_friends on behalf of people who are not admins....` which I have mentioned in question

Comment: You are aware that you are only allowed to use this endpoint for tagging/mentioning people in Open Graph stories, right? It is explicitly not a workaround to get “all friends” for any other purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get `taggable_friends` approved by Facebook, else it will only work for users with a role in the App. Don´t mistake this with `user_friends` and the `/me/friends` endpoint. that one you don´t need to get approved, but you only get friends who authorized your App with `/me/friends`.

**In your App Settings, click on "App Review", then on "Start a Submission". Scroll down to "Taggable Friends".**

Btw, you have to finish your App or at least create a working prototype, BEFORE you can send something in for review.

Comment: But, @luschn, as currently my app showing its status live and also I havent found any taggable_friends option for approval, can you please share any link

Comment: it does not matter if your app is "live", taggable_friends still needs to get approved. just start a review process in the app settings, you will see taggable_friends. here´s the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Comment: Thanks @luschn, I will check it and try again after approval of taggable_friends permission.